# I/O error during writeback of mmaped file

Tags: unix, posix, mmap, error-reporting

Is there any standard (POSIX etc) OS behaviour for handling errors during mmap writeback?
Is this even documented somewhere as stable implementation?

Case 1:
Some program doing `mmap()`, writing to that memory area, and doing `munmap()` or `msync(MS_SYNC)`. In this case, there is explicit place where writeback errors *could* be reported, but I don't know if they should be reported at `munmap()`/`msync()` by any standard.

Case 2:
Some program doing `mmap()`, writing to that memory area, and doing `sleep(1000)`. Writeback should be done asynchronously by the OS, but now there is no explicit place to report any errors from writeback. However, OS can send SIGBUS to the program. Again, I don't know if this   standardized.

Case 3:
Two programs (A and B) doing `mmap(MAP_SHARED)` for the same file. Program A writes something to that memory, program B should instantly see this changes and may rely on them. After some time, OS getting error while trying to writeback. Now the only reasonable behaviour I see it to kill both processes because they rely on changes that can't be made. But this looks weird.